# Multiplying elements of a column in skipping an element after each iteration

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R with one column as below , I want to create a new data frame with one column , which has the product of the elements of the existing column.

```
Column   result
2        2*3*4*5*8*6
3        3*4*5*8*6
4        4*5*8*6 
5        5*8*6
8        8*6
6        6
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rev` and `cumprod`

```
df$y <- rev(cumprod(rev(df$x)))
df

#  x    y
#1 2 5760
#2 3 2880
#3 4  960
#4 5  240
#5 8   48
#6 6    6
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(2,3,4,5,8,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`, i.e.

```
rev(Reduce(`*`, rev(df$x), accumulate = TRUE))
#[1] 5760 2880  960  240   48    6
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(y = accumulate_right(x, `*`))
#  x    y
#1 2 5760
#2 3 2880
#3 4  960
#4 5  240
#5 8   48
#6 6    6
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(2,3,4,5,8,6))
```